# ogr2ogr: -clipsrc or -clipdst?

Tags: clip, ogr2ogr

I am trying to replace a naïve bounding box clip when I download data for a study area using ogr2ogr, to one that uses a study area layer with an actual geometry.

ogr2ogr supports both `-clipdst` and `-clipsrc` arguments. The documentation gives this explantory text:

> Clip geometries to one of the following:
>
> - the specified bounding box (expressed in source SRS)
> - a WKT geometry (POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON expressed in source SRS)
> - one or more geometries selected from a datasource
> - the spatial extent of the -spat option if you use the spat_extent keyword.
>
> When specifying a datasource, you will generally want to use -clipsrc in combination of the -clipsrclayer, -clipsrcwhere or -clipsrcsql options.

However, it is *the same text for both `-clipdst` and `-clipsrc`*. So I'm left wondering what the difference is. My assumption is that `-clipsrc` applies a clip (whether bbox, geom, etc.) to the *source*, whereas `-clipdst` applies to the output that is being written.

My situation is this: I'm using a layer (from PostgreSQL) to clip geometries being dowloaded from a WFS endpoint to a GPKG. **Should I use `-clipsrc` or `-clipdst`**?

Presumably `-clipsrc` might put the work onto the server, but `-clipdst` (without `-clipsrc`) would do it on the client end, but I don't know. I don't know if it's redundant to give both. None of the layers I'm downloading are so large that I can't download them in their entirety and then clip—presumably if that wasn't the case I'd need to `-clipsrc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read more carefully https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html you will notice that the texts are not the same.

**-clipsrc [xmin ymin xmax ymax]|WKT|datasource|spat_extent**

- the specified bounding box (expressed in **source** SRS)
- a WKT geometry (POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON expressed in source SRS)

**-clipdst [   ]|WKT|datasource**

- the specified bounding box (expressed in **destination** SRS)
- a WKT geometry (POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON expressed in **destination** SRS)

If you do not re-project the data with `-t_srs` then the both options will give the same result.

Maybe the old documentation described the difference better. See for example https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ogr2ogr.1.html

> -clipdst xmin ymin xmax ymax
>
> (starting with GDAL 1.7.0) clip geometries after reprojection to the
> specified bounding box (expressed in dest SRS), WKT geometry (POLYGON
> or MULTIPOLYGON) or from a datasource.

Comment: OK, good catch. I'm reprojecting as I download, so I should use `-clipdst` and ensure that my datasource used with that is in the same (i.e. destination) CRS.